# Javascript Cross domain URL request

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsonp

Is it possible to send the cross domain URL request and read the response using JSONP?

Could you please give me some samples?

I am trying to send URL request to a different domain using xhr but couldn't read the response

Please help

Thanks in Advance

Comment: check if the source url has cors enabled.

Comment: @Jai you mean the domain where I am sending request? But do we need to check that even for JSON-P cross domain requests?

Comment: see that only happens when the domain you are hitting should enable the cors to share data.

Comment: Generally you can't make `Cross Domain Ajax Request` until unless server specifically allows you to do so. There is a `Response Header` responsible for controlling (`Access-Control-Allow-Origin`). It contains rules for who can access the content and who can't. This Header must be included in the response.

Answer (score 4):

You can check with blow example:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$.ajax({ // ajax call starts
        //crossOrigin: true,
       type: "GET",
       url: 'http://www.google.com', // JQuery loads areas
       dataType: 'json', // Choosing a JSON datatype
       async: false,
       success: function(data) // Variable data contains the data we get from serverside
       {
        console.log(data);

       }
      });
});
```